# what is the impact of faction support and character level on game?

Tags: necromunda-hired-gun

In *Necromunda - Hired Gun* you can do side jobs for various factions: from lowly gangs to Inquisition and Chaos Cults. You can see the how much they like you in the "Factions" tab

[image]

But what is the impact of those levels on the gameplay? Do you get better missions from factions that like you more?

In a similar fashion, I can see sometimes that my character "has gained a level". In other games, it would obviously mean that my character became stronger, but AFAIK the only way to make yourself stronger is by getting better gear. Or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My findings as far as I played:

**Faction Reputation**: On completion (all bars), unlocks a Tier 3 equipment (weapons/suits/items/...). --update: I tried to finish another faction and got 2 tier purple instead of 1 tier 3 (Promethium Guild - suit and a charm).

**Character Level**: Leveling unlocks a weapon skin (the ones that cost 80.000).

When you finish a mission, it shows that you unlocked a weapon skin.

You get stronger with equipments and with the Doc.